# Pygame: Player has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python

I'm making a 2d shooter game but when I run it, I get an error and python tells me "Player has no attribute 'rect'".

Here is the coding for my 'Player'

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def _init_(self):
    super().  __init__()

    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image=pygame.Surface([20,20])
    self.image.fill(COLOUR2)
    self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
    player.rect.x=20
```

Here is the coding for my whole game:

```
import pygame
import sys
import math

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 700))

COLOUR2 = (32,59,202)
COLOUR = (0,180,0)
COLOUR3 =(1,234,254)
WINDOW.fill(COLOUR)

keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
y=100    
z=100    
x=100    
FPS=70
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()

#Defines what a pygame bullet is.
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().  __init__()

        self.image=pygame.Surface
        self.image.fill(COLOUR2)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y-=3

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    super().  __init__()

    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image=pygame.Surface([20,20])
    self.image.fill(COLOUR2)
    self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
    player.rect.x=20

all_sprites_list=pygame.sprite.Group()#List of all the sprites
bullets_lis=pygame.sprite.Group()#List of all the bullets
player=Player()#Creates a player sprite and adds it to the small sprite list
all_sprites_list.add(player)#Adds the players to the list

while True:                 

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #Makes Player character move right by pressing "d" 
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x=x+3
        if x> 900:
            x=900
    #Makes player character move left by pressing "a"
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x=x-3
        if x<0:
            x=0
    #Makes bullets shoot out of player character by pressing *space*
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        bullet=Bullet()
        bullet.rect.x=player.rect.x
        bullet.rect.y=player.rect.y
        all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
        bullet_list.add(bullet)

    pygame.display.update()
#Updates all sprites (makes them move)
    all_sprites_list.update()
#Draws all the sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(WINDOW)

    pygame.display.flip()


    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

I have corrected the grammatical errors you guys told me about but i'm still being told the same thing. AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'rect'.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]? Can you include a stack trace for the exception?

Comment: I notice that your `__init__` method is misnamed `_init_`. That means it won't be run when your object is instantiated.

Comment: You don't have a constructor. A constructor must have the name `__init__`, but you have it misspelled. Make sure the name is correct.

Comment: I did what you guys said, but it give me this: "AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'rect' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `player.rect` you should use `self.rect` in the definition since it is the definition for `Player`

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().  __init__()

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.Surface([20,20])
        self.image.fill(COLOUR2)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=20
```